# randomly select position in array with condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
A = [[1,0,2,3],
     [2,0,1,1],
     [3,1,0,0]]
```

and I want to get the position of one of the cells with the value == 1 such as `A[0][0]` or `A[1][2]` and so on ...

So far I did this:

```
A = np.array([[1,0,2,3],
              [2,0,1,1],
              [3,1,0,0]])

B = np.where(A == 1)

C = []
for i in range(len(B[0])):
    Ca = [B[0][i], B[1][i]]
    C.append(Ca)

D = random.choice(C)
```

But now I want to reuse D for getting a cell value back. Like:

`A[D]` (which does not work) should return the same as `A[1][2]`

Does someone how to fix this or knows even a better solution?

Comment: What is your expected input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to randomly select one of the cells where `A` is 1. You can use `numpy` for this all the way through instead of having to resort to for-loops

```
B = np.array(np.where(A == 1))

>>> B
array([[0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3, 1]])
```

Now to randomly select a column corresponding to one of the cells, we can use `np.random.randint`

```
column = np.random.randint(B.shape[1])
D = B[:, column]

>>> D
array([1, 2])  # corresponds to the second index pair in B
```

Now you can simply index into `A` using the tuple of `D` (to correpond to the dimensions' indices) as

```
>>> A[tuple(D)]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
A = np.array([[1,0,2,3],
              [2,0,1,1],
              [3,1,0,0]])

B = np.where(A == 1)

C = []
for i in range(len(B[0])):
    Ca = [B[0][i], B[1][i]]
    C.append(Ca)


D = random.choice(C)
print(A[D[0]][D[1]])
```

This gives the output.

```
>>> print(A[D[0]][D[1]])
1
```

Since the value of D would be of the sort `[X,Y]`, the value could be obtained from the matrix as `A[D[0]][D[1]]`